# Can accelerometer values be used regularly (or continuously)?

Tags: android, android-sensors

I don't want to use `accelerometer` values [only on change](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEventListener.html).

I want to use them `regularly`, to keep track of their changes with respect to the change in time. So, I want to use `accelerometer` values each `t milliseconds`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the accelerometer's updates rate by setting the samplingPeriodUs in registerListener(SensorEventListener listener, Sensor sensor, int samplingPeriodUs). From [the android document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#registerListener(android.hardware.SensorEventListener,%20android.hardware.Sensor,%20int)), you may set the value of samplingPeriodUs to the desired delay between events in microseconds. But remember that the events would not triggered exactly on time, it usually receive value faster than you specified.

But remember you must catch the event by onSensorChanged method after you call registerListener. Note that the accelerometer always change, even you put your phone on the table stably, it is very sensitive.

I hope this helps you.